# Kotlin application starts, but maven build won't compile due to "unresolved reference"

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a problem with my application which I think is related to some multi-module-troubles. I have tried to set up multi module projects based on [Baeldung-guide](https://www.baeldung.com/maven-multi-module).

I have seen several questions regarding Maven/IntelliJ compilation mismatch, but they seem have the problem that Maven build is OK, while IntelliJ build is not. Mine is the other way around. I am running IntelliJ, Maven 3.8.3, Java version: 11.0.11,

My application starts and runs nicely when building and compiling in Intellij. All is well. However, when I run a `mvn clean install`, I get a lot of unresolved reference errors:

```
[ERROR] [...]/web/src/main/kotlin/com/project/web/controller/TideWaterController.kt: (3, 22) Unresolved reference: domain
[ERROR] [...]/web/src/main/kotlin/com/project/web/controller/TideWaterController.kt: (4, 22) Unresolved reference: dto
[ERROR] [...]/web/src/main/kotlin/com/project/web/controller/TideWaterController.kt: (5, 22) Unresolved reference: service
[ERROR] [...]/web/src/main/kotlin/com/project/web/controller/TideWaterController.kt: (6, 22) Unresolved reference: service
[ERROR] [...]/web/src/main/kotlin/com/project/web/controller/TideWaterController.kt: (15, 28) Unresolved reference: KartverketService
[ERROR] [...]/web/src/main/kotlin/com/project/web/controller/TideWaterController.kt: (16, 27) Unresolved reference: TideLevelService
[ERROR] [...]/web/src/main/kotlin/com/project/web/controller/TideWaterController.kt: (25, 59) Unresolved reference: TideLevelRequest
[ERROR] [...]/web/src/main/kotlin/com/project/web/controller/TideWaterController.kt: (25, 83) Unresolved reference: TideLevel
[ERROR] [...]/web/src/main/kotlin/com/project/web/controller/TideWaterController.kt: (32, 63) Unresolved reference: TideLevel
[ERROR] [...]/web/src/main/kotlin/com/project/web/controller/TideWaterController.kt: (37, 42) Unresolved reference: TideLevel
```

My `TideWaterController` tries to reference imports from other modules, e.g. *domain*, *dto*, *service* and several others.

My **web** module is where I want to package my application, it looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>weather-data-provider</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.project</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <artifactId>web</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>kartverket-integration</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.project</groupId>
            <artifactId>dto</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>project-metadata</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And my outermost parent pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>weather-data-provider</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>project weather data provider</name>
    <description>Periodically fetching weather data and exposing api endpoints</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>domain</module>
        <module>dto</module>
        <module>kartverket-integration</module>
        <module>repository</module>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.5.10</kotlin.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <[lots of dependencies commented out for brevity]>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and my Controller is pretty simple, looking like this

```
package com.project.web.controller

import com.project.domain.TideLevel
import com.project.dto.TideLevelRequest
import com.project.service.KartverketService
import com.project.service.TideLevelService
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import java.time.LocalDate


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/tide")
class TideWaterController(
    val kartverketService: KartverketService,
    val tideLevelService: TideLevelService
) {

    @GetMapping("stationList")
    fun getStations(): String? {
        return kartverketService.getStationList()
    }

    @PostMapping("tideData", consumes = ["application/json"], produces = ["application/json"])
    fun populateTideLevels(@RequestBody tideLevelRequest: TideLevelRequest): List<TideLevel> {
        return tideLevelService
            .persistTideLevelData(tideLevelRequest)
    }

    @GetMapping("tidedbSpecific")
    fun getTideDataForRiver(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) date: LocalDate,
                            @RequestParam riverName: String): TideLevel? {
        return tideLevelService.fetchSpecific(date, riverName)
    }

    @GetMapping("tidedbAll")
    fun getPersistedTides(): MutableList<TideLevel> {
        return tideLevelService.fetchAll()
    }
}
```

If I remove one of the dependencies from web/pom.xml, then IntelliJ fails to compile in the Controller class, which is expected. But when the dependency is in place, maven still reports a compile error.

I have seen other questions pointing to a mismatch in Kotlin version bundled in IntelliJ, and the Kotlin version specified in my parent pom.
My Kotlin version bundled in IntelliJ (found in Settings -> Plugins) is 1.5.10-release.

I have also been inside Settings -> Build, execution, deployment -> Kotlin Compiler, but this also points to Kotlin stable version 1.5 and "Target JVM version 11".

I have tried deleting m2-folder, invalidating caches, but nothing seems to work out.

Does anyone have an idea? Is this related to mismatch in Kotlin compile versions? Or maybe something with the way I am packaging the application? Have I misunderstood anything in the play between Kotlin and Java?

Comment: what is the source folder for `kotlin` files? check out https://kotlinlang.org/docs/maven.html#compile-kotlin-only-source-code

Comment: As you can see in first image, source folder for kotlin files are `src/main/kotlin`. 

My `web/pom.xml` as you can see in original questions, contains all the elements in the link you mentioned, such as *sourceDirectory*, *build* -> *plugins* -> *executions*. My project is Kotlin only.

Do you have any other tips to get moving?